# Equivalents of c# solutions and projects in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

Newly I am switched from *xamarin.iOS* to *Xcode*.

In `C#` a good feature is that you have a solution that contains several projects and you can define debug/build configurations and based on them build separate projects with each other.

Now, I want to know that is there any mechanism like this in the *Xcode* too?

Actually I want to develop 3 apps that they have many shared codes. So I want to create a base project that contains shared codes (and contents) and then 3 sub projects. Now with some thing like build configuration, I can build each of them that I want for publishing.

Does *Xcode* support mechanisms for this porpose?

**UPDATE**

By reading below answers I created a workspace with below structure:

[image]

I also added `../testproject/testproject` to the `build settings` of `link1Project` but when I want to use files in `testproject` the autosuggest is not working and also when I build the link1Project I face with:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ShowAlertView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in mftTbnFlipsideViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I wrong in creating the `workspace`? Does the structure is right or I missed something?

Comment: briefly, yes – the Xcode supports such thing.

Comment: try custom pods with [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple targets for the same project, and each target can have different settings or files.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this base project as a sub-project to each of those 3 projects (just drag it). And create a workspace to include all three child project in it, although it is not necessary - including project as a sub-project is enougth to share code between projects.

Comment: And how can I select witch project should build when I build the workspace?

Comment: you can select it in the selector near run/stop buttons in the top left corner of xcode window

Comment: I add the project as a sub-project too but I can not '#import' the files of the sub-project and also can not build the project. What is wrong?

Comment: You project structure should look like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzms3fdwtelfuvs/so1.png